# Cannot resign searchbar a second time

Tags: ios, swift

I really don't understand why this is happening.  Any hints would be much appreciated.

Setup:
`UIViewController` with the following subviews:

1. `UISearchBar`
2. `UITextField`
3. `UIView` (with PickerView and Done button) - viewDidLoad hides it.

I have two helper functions which can be simplified as:

```
func showPickerView () {
  myPickerSubView.alpha = 1
}

func hidePickerView () {
  myPickerSubView.alpha = 0
}
```

(There's actually animation, sliding up and down etc. but that part works fine)

What I want is for `myPickerSubView` to show when the person taps on the `UISearchBar` or the `UITextField`.  myPickerSubView is dismissed by the Done button on `myPickerSubview`.

I started with the `UITextField` which I got working perfectly with:

```
  func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField)
  {
    if !(pickerSubViewVisible) 
    {
      self.showPickerView()
    }
    eventFloorTextField.endEditing(true)
  }

  func pickerView(eventFloorPicker: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row:Int, inComponent component: Int {
    //.. other processing code
    self.eventFloorTextField.text = "My Pick: \(myPick)" //so the textfield gets updated
  }
```

I wanted to use a `UISearchBar` instead because I wanted to uses the built in scope bar for some added functionality.  So having set the `UISearchBar` delegate to self etc. I thought I could just do:

```
  func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar)
  {
    eventFloorSearchBar.endEditing(true)
    self.showPickerView()
  }
```

When you press on the `UISearchBar` the first time, the `PickerSubView` shows up as expected.  Then, no matter what I do (press on my Textfield, dismiss the `PickerSubView` or not,) if I tap on the `UISearchBar` a second time, a keyboard will come up from the bottom.  If my `PickerSubView` is already present, the keyboard will cover it.  If the `PickerSubView` is not present, if I tap on the `UITextField`, the `PickerSubView` will slide up behind the keyboard.

I do not know if it is significant - but the caret (blinking cursor) remains in the `UISearchBar` text field but even if I make it go away by tapping on the `UITextfield` first, when I tap `UISearchBar` a second time, it will always be a keyboard showing up.

I've tried `resignFirstResponder` as well as various other methods, but none of them seem to work.

Comment: try to set your `PickerSubview` as `inputView` of `searchBar` - that way you prevent keyboard to slide out

Comment: I think u can set input view for a button but in UISeachbar - it is a read only value that by default is nil.  I tried to subclass UISearchbar and then override "inputView" as per Apple's suggestion to make it "read/write" but was not successful in that regard...